# how to perform a query by the field as well as the record type

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckquery

I was wondering if it was possible to search for a CKRecord by not only its record type but as well as its field in the database. For example heres my code I have now to fetch records:

```
        database.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil, completionHandler: { (records:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!) in

            // Check if there's an error
            if error != nil {
                NSLog(error.localizedDescription)

            }
            else {

            }

        })
```

This only searches through the record type and for my program I need to be able to go deeper and specify a field as well to search through. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CKQuery documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html) shows you how to build more complex queries. Here is a simple example:

```
let firstName = "John"
let age = 20

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "firstName = %@ AND age >= %@", firstName, NSNumber(integer: age))

let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Employee", predicate: predicate)
```